# How do I run my XBOX XNA game without a network connection?

Tags: xna, networking, xbox, deployment

I need to demo my XBOX XNA game in college. The college doesn't allow this type of device to connect to the network. I deployed my game to the Xbox and it is sitting in the games list along with my other games. It runs fine with a network connection but when its offline it comes up with an error message saying its needs a connection to run the game.

This makes no sense, the game is deployed on the Xbox memory, it must be some security policy or something!

Is there any way around this? The demo is on monday!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you're out of luck. XBLIG games, whether published or unpublished, require an Internet connection to run. I see two alternatives:

1) Use a mobile phone to set up your own mini-network and somehow give your Xbox an Internet connection.

2) Use a laptop to demo your game instead. XNA games run on PC. Xbox controllers can be plugged into a PC via USB (if your controllers are wireless you need to buy a receiver). Laptops can be plugged into external displays, if that's a needed feature (and most colleges should be well-equipped for plugging laptops into projectors already).

Comment: The laptop suggestion seems the be the best solution.

Comment: That's how I've seen them presented at college expos before. You can't really even tell the difference once it's on a TV screen and in game with the controllers.

Comment: sorry for not getting back, yeah i got lucky i was allowed connect it directly for like 5 minutes and that did the job. I was aware of the laptop option, i dont have one and also i wanted to show it running on the intended platform! the mobile phone idea was great though, would have tryed that! thanks a lot guys!